# Looking for a common word meaning hands and feet as well

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes/means the appendices at the ends of limbs (namely hands and feet), meaning a singular one of them.

*Bonus:* a word that describes/means all of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the plural, consider *[extremities](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extremities)*.  Its singular is *[extremity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extremity#Noun)*.

From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extremity#Noun), *extremity* has a sense (among others) of “A hand or foot”.

(It also has a sense of “A limb”, ie an arm or leg, so may be imperfect for your needs.)

As noted in tunny's comment, [collinsdictionary.com](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/extremities) shows similar definitions, for *extremities* and *extremity* respectively, with emphasis added:

> • (formal) **hands and feet**
>   • a limb, such as a leg, arm, or wing, or **the part of such a limb farthest from the trunk**

The terms *[appendage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appendage#Noun)* and *[appendages](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appendages)* are relevant too, although rather less specific to hands and feet than are *extremity* and *extremities*.   From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appendage#Noun), *appendage* means “an external body part that projects from the body”.  Most humans have five main appendages, ie head, arms, legs.  Typical human males have another appendage, or *[member](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/member#Noun)*, sense 4.  I don't know if breasts count as appendages.  If we count fingers and toes as minor appendages, I suppose noses and ears should count as well.

Comment: The Collins dictionary agrees: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/extremities

Comment: Sometimes I think languages get me cold. It's the same word in my native tongue (German) but I couldn't think of it.. thanks

Comment: So according to Collins, angels must possess six extremities. (Good to know!) ...Unless they actually have *four* wings, of course. (Could they have an *odd* number of wings, I wonder?)

Comment: @Eric Kowal Angels have 4 or 6 wings. == Eze:1:5: Also out of the midst thereof came the likeness of four living creatures.  And this was their appearance; they had the likeness of a man. Eze:1:6: And every one had four faces, and every one had four wings. == Isa:6:2: Above it stood the seraphims: each one had six wings; with twain he covered his face, and with twain he covered his feet, and with twain he did fly.